# Scala: Start an identifier with a digit

Tags: scala

I want to write an identifier which starts with a digit inside an enumeration but it gives 'Invalid literal number error'. Something like:

```
val 30Over360US = Value
```

How do I make it happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use almost any identifier with the help of backticks:

```
val `30Over360US` = Value
```